# Bubble and falling baloons effects in cocos2d for iphone?

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible to do following effects in cocos2d for iphone.
1) Boiling water with bubbles
2) balloons falling down

Comment: Yes.  You could do it by animating sprites, but you might want to look at their Particle Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Particle Designer](http://particledesigner.71squared.com/) from 71 Squared, it's really helpful.